# $\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{dx \, dy}{1+x^{10}y^{10}}$ diverges or converges?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Question I'm trying to solve to prepare for an exam.

I need to find out if $\displaystyle\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{dx\,dy}{1+x^{10}y^{10}}$ diverges or converges.

What I did:

I switched to polar coordinates, $x=r\cos \theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, $J=r$

and so

$$
\begin{align}
\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{dx\,dy}{1+x^{10}y^{10}} & =\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{r}{1+r^{20} \sin \theta \cos \theta} \, dr \, d\theta \\[8pt]
& < \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{r^{19}\sin \theta \cos \theta} \, dr \, d\theta \\[8pt]
& = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{r^{19}\sin 2\theta} \, dr \, d\theta \\[8pt]
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin 2\theta} \, d\theta \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{r^{19}}\,dr
\end{align}
$$

But note that both $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{r^{19}}dr$ and $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin 2\theta} \, d\theta$ do not converge, so we proved nothing.

So that is not the way.

Does this integral converge/ diverge? why?

And also, I'd like to know why $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin 2\theta} \, d\theta$ does not converge. I know it doesn't because of wolfram, not because i showed it on paper.

Comment: Recall that $\sin(x)\sim _0x$.

Comment: Yes that is correct. that explains why $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin 2\theta} d\theta$ does not converge.

Comment: First note that there is no trouble near $(0,0)$. In the unit circle with centre the origin, our function is $\le 1$. So you can confine attention to $r\gt 1$.

Comment: I agree with this statement, and furthermore, $\int_{1}^{\infty} r^{-19}dr$ converges. however, $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sin 2\theta}$ still diverges

Comment: $r^{20}\sin^{10}\theta\cos^{10}\theta$ should have appeared there.

Comment: Yes, a typo. no matter, there are plenty good answers now. 1 of which is my own.

Comment: @OriaGruber I reckon the exam must be around the corner. Good luck.

Comment: In a week, god help me

Comment: no,no, gud help you

Comment: @GitGud, I have promoted you, see preceding comment

Comment: @WillJagy Ahahah. Are you like this when you teach?

Comment: @GitGud, yes, but that was years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Draw the shape around the axes inside the two hyperbolas, and four arcs, given by $xy=1$ and $xy=-1.$ Sort of a cross shape, but infinite, with both axes in its interior. Within this, $x^{10} y^{10} \leq 1,$ then  $1 +x^{10} y^{10} \leq 2,$ finally
$$ \frac{1}{1 +x^{10} y^{10}} \geq \frac{1}{2}. $$
This region has infinite area, the integral (nonnegative integrand) on the region is infinite. Being a little careful, out to some radius $R,$ the integral on the shape is at least half the area out to that radius; as $R \rightarrow \infty,$ so do the area and the integral.

Answer (score 4):

A trivial way to see the integral fails to converge is to observe that $$\frac{1}{1+(x y)^{2n}} > \frac{1}{2}$$ whenever $|xy| < 1$, and this occurs over a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ with obviously infinite area.

Answer (score 2):

Using a tip a friend gave me: It is enough to work on the first quadrant due to symmetry.

We will instead use the transform $v=xy, u=x$, the jacobian of said transform is $\frac{1}{u}$ which can be demonstrated.

$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{1}{1+x^{10}y^{10}}dx\,dy = \int_0^\infty \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+v^{10}} \frac{1}{u} \, dv \, du =\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+v^{10}} \, dv \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{u} \, du  $$

Notice that $\frac{1}{1+v^{10}}>0$ and so $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+v^{10}} \, dv>0$, and that $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{u} \, du$ diverges.

We can infer that the original integral diverges as well.

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=double+integral&a=*MC.~-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=1%2F(1%2Bx%5E10y%5E10)&f=DoubleIntegral.integrand%5Cu005f1%2F(1%2Bx%5E10y%5E10)&f3=x+&f=DoubleIntegral.intvariable1%5Cu005fx+&f4=0&f=DoubleIntegral.rangestart1%5Cu005f0&f5=infinity&f=DoubleIntegral.rangeend1_infinity&f6=y+&f=DoubleIntegral.intvariable2%5Cu005fy+&f7=0&f=DoubleIntegral.rangestart2%5Cu005f0&f8=infinity&f=DoubleIntegral.rangeend2_infinity) agrees that it does not converge

Comment: @RossMillikan, there is an easy argument, posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Scale $\quad\ds{\verts{x}y}\quad$ to $\quad\ds{y}\quad$ and you are left with a result $\quad\ds{\propto \int{\dd x \over \verts{x}}}\quad$ which 'diverges logarithmically'.